# Forcing remote client to calling stored procedures

Tags: sql-server

How can I force remote client applications to call my stored procedure?

I want to deny the direct execution of SQL statements from remote clients.

Can I do that?

Making the stored procedure do the entire job is it bad choice from performance perspective and security perspective

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> can I do that ?

Sure.  You create a user/login for the application to use and assign it to just the public role on the database.  Then grant it execute permissions on the required stored procedures.  The application generally doesn't need access to the underlying objects the stored procedure calls.

> making the stored procedure do the entire job is it bad choice from performance perspective and security perspective

Performance will depend on the stored procedures and overall database design.  There's no general reason performance couldn't be perfectly acceptable, however.

Security-wise, you only grant access to what you want the user/login to access and that's good.  Again, there's no general reason security wouldn't be perfectly acceptable.